Share config across YAML files
I have multiple files that all specify the same build target and Xcode version like this
jobs:
  deploy:
    environment: production
    runs-on: macos-14  # <------------------------ This
    steps:
      - uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
        with:
          xcode-version: '15.0.1'  # <------------ This

I'd like to specify this config once, I don't want to specify them as variables in the dashboard since I want to be able to have different branches use different versions (and have all the config be in code).
I can think of ways of hacking my way around achieving this for the xcode-version (e.g. loading the value from a config file) but I'm stuck on the runs-on value.
